# 1 mod p: what is significance of this other than writing 1

Tags: theory, computation-theory

I am working on a theory of computing assignment.

I have a question
Let p ∈ N, p > 4. We have a DFA A = (Σ, Q, δ, 0, F) with Q = {0, 1, . . . , k},
k ≥ p, and there is a ∈ Σ such that we have δ(q, a) = q + 1 mod p, for all states q ∈ Q. In
these conditions:
(a) show by induction on n that for all n ≥ 0 and q < p, δ(q, a^(n·p)) = q;

I am confused because q + 1modp....isn't this just 1? if so this seems to make my question unproveable

Comment: I would rather read this as `δ(q, a) = q + 1 (mod p)` - `δ(q, a)` and `q + 1` are congruent modulo `p`.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt that it's `q + (1 mod p)`, which would *indeed* be `q + 1`, given the constraint that  `p > 4`.

It's far more likely to be `(q + 1) mod p`, which is a totally different beast.

Comment: I _don't_ know for certain but, as you say, treating  it the way you assume doesn't make a lot of sense. Your comment that it makes your question unprovable should (by applying proof by contradiction) make that obvious :-)

Comment: ok cool..Still might be equally as hard to solve but we shall see :D

Answer (score 0):

1 mod 1 is 0, so 1 mod p doesn't have to be 1...

Comment: Actually, while you're correct in general, I don't think that reasoning applies in this _particular_ case since `p ∈ N, p > 4` (ie, `p` cannot be `1`).

Comment: I know, just wanted to point out 1 mod a number doesnt have to be 1...